# How represent the following code in mathematical notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, python

I'm trying to represent the following code in one equation, But I'm confused about that

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2]
for i in a:
  temp = []
  for j in b:
    temp.append(i+j)
  result=sum(temp)/len(b)
```

the result should not be as vector like 
first iteration the result will be 2.5 , the second 3.5 and third iteration the result will be 4.5

Comment: Where did you get this code from, do you know what it's trying to do?

Comment: I wrote this code, but  I'm a  little bit confused how to represent it in eq

Comment: What kind of equation are you looking for?  Since the result is a vector, are you looking for some kind of equation in terms of vectors? Or would you be ok with an equation for each element of the vector?  Maybe more to the point: Since you seem to understand what the code is doing, what is the goal/purpose of this alternative equation? What are you trying to do? How would this new equation be used?

Comment: @Bram28 yes it's ok with an equation for each element of the vector

Comment: What would be the variables of the equation? The length of $a$? The length of $b$? Or just $a$ and $b$ ... so that we can use $len(a)$ and $len(b)$?  Can you use $a[i]$ as a function to pick out the $i$-th element from $a$?

Comment: Wouldn't the first element be $\frac{1+1}{2} = 1$ ? Since i read it as i$=1$ and j$=1$ and sum(temp)$=2$ and len = $2$ in the first computation. But I dont know Python so maybe im just confused about this language. Never mind. I didnt see the innerloop.

Comment: @Bram28 the length of a will be len(a) and length of b  will be len(b)

Comment: OK, I added my Answer, assuming any two vectors $a$ and $b$, of length $len(a)$ and $len(b)$, and whose elements are can be obtained using $a[i]$ and $b[j]$, respectively

Comment: @Bram28 but I don't want the result to be vector.

Comment: But [1.5,2.5,3.5] *is* a vector.  Anyway, I indicated what each element in the vector will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a programmer. I would treat both **a** and **b** as two finite sets since their domains are finite.

Define set $a$ of length $n$ as $a(n) = a_n$ for $a=\{1,2,3\}$.

Define set $b$ of length $m$ as $b(m) = b_m$ for $b=\{1,2\}$.

Define an sequence of $c$ with length $n$:
$$c_i=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{m} (a_i+b_j)}{m}$$

I dunno if this notation is mathematically acceptable though.

Comment: why do we need parentheses?

Comment: I dont think we really need that. I did for safety.

Comment: Clarity i meant.

Comment: I removed the parentheses.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy: We need parentheses around $a_i+b_j$, since otherwise $b_j$ is just a constant out of the scope of the sigma symbols and not related with the index $j$. You might want to check the Wiki for bound versus unbound variables.

Comment: ok, so that was my suspicious feeling. fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, $\text{result}$ contains one item per item in $a$, obtained as said item plus the mean of $b$. So we can write $\text{result}_i=a_i+\bar{b}$ or, if we work with vectors, $\text{result}=a+\bar{b}1$, with $1$ a vector whose entries are each equal to one. This is by no means the only way to describe the outcome in mathematical notation, but it is one way.

Answer (score 0):

For element result[i] (if you start counting i by 1) you have simple:

result[i] = $\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{j=1}^{2} (i + j))$

Comment: My coment "if you start counting i by 1" means, we assume that the index of your first element is 1. But in most languagues the first index is 0. In this case we just has to write: result[i-1] = $1/2 (\sum_{j=1}^{2}(i+j))$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start with vectors $a$ and $b$, with lengths $len(a)$ and $len(b)$ respectively, and where $a[i]$ and $b[j]$ represent the $i$-th and $j$-element from $a$ and $b$ respectively, the result would be a vector $c$ of length $len(a)$, and such that:

$$\text{for all} \ 1 \leq i \leq len(a): c[i]=\frac{1}{len(b)}\cdot \sum_{j=1}^{len(b)} (a[i]+b[j])$$

And if you don't like vectors:

The first result will be:

$$\frac{1}{len(b)}\cdot \sum_{j=1}^{len(b)} (a[1]+b[j])$$

The second result will be:

$$\frac{1}{len(b)}\cdot \sum_{j=1}^{len(b)} (a[2]+b[j])$$

Etc.

I.e. in general, the $i$-th result will be:

$$\frac{1}{len(b)}\cdot \sum_{j=1}^{len(b)} (a[i]+b[j])$$